# How to delete User With tags on azure notification hub?

Tags: azure, apple-push-notifications, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

How can i delete a device with tag ,means i have ios Device Token and the tag that device registered with i need to delete this user from backend?

And also how i can access to list of users details like count by tag or /and device tokens that registered to azure notification hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete a tag you just update the registration with a set of tags that does *not* contain it. E.g.

```
SBRegistration* toUpdate = [hub retrieveNativeRegistrationWithError: nil];
[[toUpdate tags] addObjectsFromArray: @[@"myNewTag1", @"myOtherNewTag"]];
[hub updateRegistration:toUpdate];
```

Or Async:

```
[hub retrieveNativeRegistrationWithCompletion:^(SBRegistration* r, NSError* e) {
    if (r == nil) ; // error handling
    [[r tags] addObjectsFromArray:@[@"myNewTag", @"myOtherNewTag"]];
    [hub updateRegistration:r completion:^(SBRegistration* r2, NSError* e) {
        // error mgmt;
    }];
}];
```

Also, note that when you call createNativeRegistration you will overwrite the current set of tags. This naming inconsistency is getting fixed in the next release of the iOS SDK.

At this moment you cannot retrieve count by tag, but (from the back-end) you can retrieve all registrations with a tag (an inefficient a way to count).
You can do it from the back-end .NET SDK, using:

```
var skip = 0;
var increment = 100;
IEnumerable<RegistrationDescription> regs = hubClient.GetRegistrationsByTag("myTag", skip, increment);
while (regs.Count() != 0)
{
    foreach (var i in regs)
    {
        // do work
    }
    skip += increment + 1;
    regs = hubClient.GetRegistrationsByTag("myTag", skip, increment);
}
```

Or using our REST surface: [GetRegistrationsByTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn223274.aspx)

Thanks,

Elio

Comment: Thanks Elio

Let's say we have 10 clubs i as ios user want to register in 4 clubs
so i go and follow for example soocer , basketball , tennis ,
ping-pong

Each club that i want to register i have to call native registration with tag

So that part you mentioned for overwrite is this? once i register
for basketball it is not seconded registration and update soccer to
basketball ?

And also in case user going to unfollow on of this clubs once i update
to @"newtag1"
It will update all and not just unfollow that club

Is it right ? And any solution ?

Comment: You should update the registration only when you know all the clubs you want to follow. The guidance is to have stored the clubs that the user wants to follow somewhere (e.g. in your local storage) then when you want to add/remove a tag, update the master list in the local storage and then update the registration by setting the tags property to your set of tags

Comment: Thanks Elio ,
i think this is possible and can solve our problem we are going to use this cool service for long term so please update in to help us more 
and also we are waiting for android and windows phone support as well

again thank you and have nice day ;-)